# How to "round" number, by putting zeros after the 2nd digit in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to "round" an integer number, by swapping all the digits after the 2nd digit to zeros. Additionally, if the number has only 1 digit, then don't do anything, and if the number has 2 digits, then swap the 2nd digit to a 0.

Example:

```
3 => 3
22 => 20
754 => 750
8912 => 8900
```

Can this be achieved without truncating the number as a string, and then rebuilding the number with zeros?

Comment: Are you actually rounding?

Comment: Can you please share your logic what you have tried till now ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add quotes to the "round"  wording. It's not real rounding, I just want the digits after the 2nd digit to become zeros.

Comment: Your example of `22` being changed to `20` seems wrong, by your description of what you want. *edit* oh wait I see. Anyway you can do this numerically by dividing by some power of 10, truncating the fractional part (via `Math.floor()`), and then multiplying that by the same power of 10.

Comment: so divide, floor, multiply....

Comment: And probably get the base-10 logarithm of the number and truncate it to find your power of 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work with every base-10 number.

All is about a simple math operation: `number - [rest of (number / base-10 of number)]`

```js
function round(n) {
  if(n < 10) return n;
  var d = getTenBase(n.toString().length - 1);
  return n - (n % (10 * d));
}

function getTenBase(l) {
  var d = 1;
  for(var i = 2; i < l; i++) {
    d *= 10;
  }
  return d;
}

console.log(round(3));
console.log(round(22));
console.log(round(768));
console.log(round(1657));
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to truncate the number as a string, it can be easily achieved via mathematical calculation. Also, changing number to string and then doing any operation will be an added overhead which is not required in this case.

Refer the code below, it's quite straight forward.
Hope this helps.

```js
function changeNumber(num){
 if(Math.floor(num/10) == 0){
  return num;
    } else if(Math.floor(num/1000) == 0){
  return Math.floor(num/10)*10;
    }
 else{
  return Math.floor(num/100)*100
    }
}
 
console.log(changeNumber(3));
console.log(changeNumber(22));
console.log(changeNumber(754));
console.log(changeNumber(8923));
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Point noted, will keep in mind while answering next questions. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! This one works nicely. I also started to understand the problem. I overcomplicated with the fact that I started counting digits, and adding 10 to the power of the number of digits found - 2....This works nicely

Comment: Update: forgot to test this for numbers with more than 4 digits... the else part has to be adjusted, so we consider the number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

you can just find length and first two character after that take zero with valid length and concat both

var str = '8912';
var n = str.length;

if(n == 1)
{

print(str);
} else if(n==2) {

```
var strFirst = str.substring(0,1);
var str2 = '0';
var res = strFirst.concat(str2);
```

}  else if(n>2) {

```
var strFirst = str.substring(0,2);

var i;
 var strsec ='0';
for (i = 0; i < n-3; i++) {
strsec += 0 ;
```

}

var res = strFirst.concat(strsec);

}
print(res);